# Using a different persistence unit for testing

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

I have several stateless session beans I have created unit tests for. When I run these tests in the embedded GlassFish container, the default persistence unit for my project is used, which is a local MySQL database for development purposes. When running the unit tests however, I wish to use the embedded Derby database so that any unit testing does not clutter the database with mock data.

In OpenEJB, it is possible to override persistence.xml by creating a hash map and putting some properties, like so:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"org.apache.openejb.client.LocalInitialContextFactory");

p.put("movie-unit.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
p.put("movie-unit.hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect");

context = new InitialContext(p);
```

Is the same or something similar possible with Sun's implementation to run unit tests on a different database?

**Edit:** I am using Ant to build the project. I guess it would be possible to copy the testing persistence.xml when running a test, and copy the regular persistence.xml for deployments but this seems clunky. Would switching to Maven be advisable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what sort of build tool you're using.

In Maven you have a separation between runtime and test resources:

```
project 
 |- src/main/resources
 |- src/test/resources
```

The ones in `src/test/resources` aren't included in your final artifact and are only used by the unit testing plugin (Surefire) during the testing phase of the build.

Whatever the tool, I suggest you have this sort of separation between the resources in order to be able to achieve the result you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks Carl, I am using Ant to build the project and have updated the question. I could go on and create this separation but if Maven supports this out of the box, would it be advisable to switch, having no prior experience with it?

Comment: If your build script is simple, I would recommend switching as soon as possible. Ant's a great tool, but there's a lot of things which are covered out of the box in Maven and this is one of the cases.

Comment: I was still using the default script so I copied my source files over to a new Maven project and based on your advice and [link](http://pschyska.blogspot.com/2011/06/unit-testing-ejb-31-with-netbeans-maven.html) I was able to get this working. Thanks!